# Unable to run Cypress 9.7.0 tests in Firefox

Tags: cypress

My Cypress tests run as expected in Chrome, Electron, & Edge.

However, when I try to run these tests against Firefox, I get the below error:

> Cypress failed to make a connection to Firefox.
>
> This usually indicates there was a problem opening the Firefox
> browser.
>
> Error: could not find CRI target
> at lazyAssLogic

I am using Cypress version`9.7.0`, & using the below command:

```
"scripts": {
  "firefoxTest": "cypress run --browser firefox"
}
```

One thing that may be important is that I'm using `failOnStatusCode` in some of the tests.

I've seen there have been similar issues before with earlier versions of Cypress such as [this issue](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/6053), but I believe that has been fixed in a later release.

Can someone please tell me what the issue may be?

Answer (score 0):

By installing a older version from firefox (v 99) i could solve it. The idea i got from this forum https://issuehint.com/issue/cypress-io/cypress/22086 and the link for downloading an older version is from here https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/99.0/win64/en-US/. Hope this helps